# Wordpress imagens não aparecem

Tags: php, wordpress

estou com um problema em um site wordpress, quando entro na biblioteca, ela fica fica em loop infinito, realizando chamada para o admin-ajax.php e não exibe imagens.

O que pode ser? esgotei minhas idéias.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muitas pessoas têm esse problema. Dá para corrigir pelo plugin Media Library Assistant, mas não deveria ser necessário o uso de um plugin. O código principal precisa lidar com isso sem plugins. Ou tente fazer o seguintet se já não o fez.
insira no wp-config.php

```
define(‘WP_SITEURL’, <your_site_url>);`
```

Comment: Funcionou Antonius valeu mesmo irmão, nunca tinha me acontecido isso, mas já anotei aqui. Valeu mesmo abração.